# Can the condition of nonempty interior be removed in the hyperplane separation theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Consider the following hyperplane separation theorem: Suppose $E$ is a proper convex subset in a normed vector space $\mathcal{X}$ and $\theta$ (the origin) is an interior point of $E$. And suppose $x_0\notin E$. Then there exists a hyperplane denoted by $H_f^r$ that separates $x_0$ and $E$. Here $H_f^r=\{x| f(x)=r\}$ where $f$ is a continuous and linear functional and $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

I have learned in the book *Functional Analysis (2ed)* written in Chinese by the professor Gong-Qing Zhang from the Peking University (shown in the figure below) that **the condition of nonempty interior is necessary** when $\mathcal{X}$ is of **infinite dimensions**. How can we show this by an example? That is to say I hope to construct a counterexample of the above separation theorem if $E$'s interior is empty.
[image]
The text with blue underline in the above figure means in English:

> **But, for a infinite-dimensional normed vector space, the condition of nonempyty interior cannot be omitted.**

Moreover, can the condition of nonempty interior be removed in the case of finite dimensions? If so, how can we prove it?

Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: "You have learned"; how, and from where? Some reference for this result would be useufl

Comment: In $X=l^2$ take the set $E$ of all sequences which are eventually zero. Then $E$ is convex and dense, so you can't separate any $x_0\in X\setminus E$ from $E$.

Comment: Beautiful counterexample! Thanks a lot! @Gerd

Comment: Sorry about that. It's my fault. I forgot to post the figure as above. Thans for your reminding! @FShrike